# How to read excel and validate one column's data in the database?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am coming from java background and have minimal idea regarding python. I have to read an excel file and validate one of it's column values in the DB to verify that those rows exist in the DB or not.

I know the exact libraries and steps in java using which I can do this work. 
But I am facing problems in choosing the ways to do this work in python.

till now I am able to identify some things which I can do.

1. Read excel file in python using python.
2. Use pyodbc to validate the values.

Can pandas help me to refine those steps. Rather doing things the hard way.

Comment: by validate , what do you mean? please be more specific on what exactly you need to lookup in the column of a df. Also post a sample df and expected output for the ease of the users to answer. :)

Comment: DF as in Data frame of Pandas? My explanation is simple. Read an excel file which has a column ID. After reading the excel I will hit the Database to validate whether that ID exists in my table or not. If ID exists in the DB then a +ve message will be logged if not then a -ve message gets logged.

Comment: by database you mean sql database?:- you can either import data from sql in pandas and then lookup the values using existing solutions in SO, else just import the data in sql and then do a lookup.

Comment: Yes I am using Sql server for that purpose. Sure thing I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes pandas can help. But you phrase the question in a "please google this for me" way. Expect this question to be down-voted a lot.

I will give you the answer for the excel part. Surely you could have found this yourself with a little effort?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('excel_file.xls')
```

Read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: Yeah Robert I am using the same thing.
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile("abc.xlsx")

Answer (score 0):

Using xlrd module, one can retrieve information from a spreadsheet. For example, reading, writing or modifying the data can be done in Python. Also, a user might have to go through various sheets and retrieve data based on some criteria or modify some rows and columns and do a lot of work.

xlrd module is used to extract data from a spreadsheet.

```
# Reading an excel file using Python 
import xlrd 

# Give the location of the file 

loc = ("path of file") 

# To open Workbook 
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

# For row 0 and column 0 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
```

put open_workbook under try statement and use pyodbc.Error as exe in except to catch the error if there is any.